# How to force Ansible to recreate a docker container if mounted files have changed

Tags: docker, ansible

I'm trying to get Ansible to recreate an existing docker container in case one of the mounted files have changed. I tried to use `docker_container`to remove the container, if it exists and any file has changed, before I deploy it using `docker_stack` and a compose file. Here is the code:

```
- name: Template configuration files to destination
  template:
    ...
  loop:
    ...
  register: template_files_result

- name: Get docker container name
  shell: "docker ps -f 'name=some_name' -q"
  register: container_id

- name: Remove container
  docker_container:
    name: container_id.stdout
    force_kill: yes
    state: absent
  vars:
    files_changed: "{{ template_files_result | json_query('results[*].changed') }}"
  when: container_id.stdout and files_changed is any

- name: Deploy
  docker_stack:
    state: present
    name: stack_name
    compose:
      - "compose.yml"
    with_registry_auth: true
```

However, the `Remove container` task never does anything and I can't figure out why.

What am I missing?

Comment: `name: container_id.stdout` should be `name: "{{ container_id.stdout }}"`, and also the thing you are looking for is the [`changed` test](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#task-results) as in `when: container_id.stdout and template_files_result is changed`

Comment: @mdaniel Thanks, I made those changes. Now when I run the playbook I get the status "changed" for the "Remove container" task, however, it doesn't actually get removed. It's still up. Any ideas?

Comment: `force_kill` was the culprit. Without it the container gets removed. However, the `Deploy` task has `changed = false`, even though the container is recreated. It gets `changed = true` if I remove the container by hand. Seems wrong to me.